# Implementing Trickle Algorithm with Raspberry Pis over WiFi

Tags: linux, algorithm, networking, raspberry-pi2, adhoc

I have three Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with me and each of them have been hardcoded to IP addresses such as `192.168.50.x/24` and each of them run an avahi-daemon in order to provide the mDNS and easier to ping when using the `.local` suffix.

for instance

```
Raspberry Pi #1
IP Address 192.168.50.1 subnet 255.255.255.0
hostname: hydrogenPi
mDNS: hydrogenPi.local

Raspberry Pi #2
IP Address 192.168.50.2 subnet 255.255.255.0
hostname: heliumPi
mDNS: heliumPi.local

Raspberry Pi #3
IP Address 192.168.50.3 subnet 255.255.255.0
hostname: lithiumPi
mDNS: lithiumPi.local
```

All the Pis are working in Ad-hoc mode and are using the [batman-adv](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/open-mesh/wiki) version 2015 which is available on the Pis already.

I would like to send some files over the ad-hoc network using WiFi (Dongle used **LogiLink Wireless Adapters with Ralink RT5370 driver**) using the [Trickle Algorithm RFC Standard 6206](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6206.txt).

Are there any available code snippets or ideas where I can start the implementation of the Algorithm?

NOTE: I want to flood the ad-hoc network with data in an efficient manner and hence I was thinking of the Trickle Algorithm. SInce it is now an RFC standard does it already have implementations available in Raspberry Pis like **6LoWPAN** et.al. which I came across in `lib/modules/4.13.7+/kernel/net/` in Raspberry Pi directory ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a Python programmed repository on **GitHub**

There is a **RPL(Routing Protocol for Low-power & lossy networks)** Repository which is called [simpleRPL](https://github.com/linux-wpan/simpleRPL)

In the */RPL* folder there is a simple **Trickle Timer** implementation